# debug the onLaunch callback in firebase_messaging in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `firebase_messaging` in my flutter application, and I want to be able to debug what happens when the `onLaunch` callback fires.

The problem is that it fires when a notification is received and the app is terminated.

There has to be a way to debug it right?

Comment: The `onLauch` should be called when you tap on your notification and your app is opening up. Could you please elaborate more your needs?

Comment: Yeah right. But prior to the app opening up, the app was terminated and there was no debug connection, so when the onLaunch is called, how do I know what's happening. In my case, the app begins to execute, as I'd expect it to be, but after that, I am getting a NoSuchMethodError, and I need to know which line is causing that.

Comment: Of course you could use logs (`print(.)`) for that, But the `onLaunch` is called also if the app is in background so you could have your debugger attached to the process.

Comment: As per the table given on this page, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging onResume is called when the app is in background, could you tell me how is onLaunch called, or how can I have my debugger attached.

Comment: Also I don't really know the approach as to how I could see the logs with the print(.) messages. If you could please tell me how that is done, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right. So you could use logs or add (just for debug) the same logic you put in your `onLaunch` in your `onResume` and debug from that. As for the log you could use the `logcat` tab of Android Studio or from the [command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) `adb shell` (`-s` to select from more than one device)  to enter your device shell and then `logcat`.

Comment: So I've made a more inside on your scenario with a live example and I wrote an answer that could sum up our discussion and the method to debug with log without the debug attach and why you had problems with your message Map on your onLaunch. C'ya!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So following OP discussion you could debug the `onLaunch` with `print()` or `debugPrint()` function.

You can use the adb command line to get logcat output on terminal like this

```
$ adb shell 
$ logcat -e "flutter" -v color
```

if you have more than one device you could use the `-s` parameter in order to choose your device.

`-e` is for filter only log message that has a flutter word inside

`-v` color is to have a formatted color output

As data message are not supported by Android plugin you could send a `notification` message in order to have the `onLaunch` called providing also this `data` field:

```
"data": {"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", "id": "1", "status": "done"}
```

You can send a message like that

```
{
 "to" : "<your device token>",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "priority" : "high",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Test notification body",
     "title": "Test notification title",
     "sound": "default"
 },
 "data": {"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", "id": "1", "status": "done", "foo":"bar"}
}
```

The problem is that you get different `Map` *message* JSON:

`onMessage` you get

```
{notification: {title: Custom sound alert.mp3, body: Test Notification body for custom sound 25/01/2019}, data: {status: done, id: 1, foo: bar, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK}}
```

Instead in `onLaunch` and `onResume` you get

```
{collapse_key: com.example.flutterapptestfcmmessaging, google.original_priority: high, google.sent_time: 1548447425689, google.delivered_priority: high, foo: bar, google.ttl: 2419200, from: 945032663190, id: 1, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, google.message_id: 0:15484474256938..., status: done}
```

> 1-25 21:14:43.802  3445  3491 I flutter : onLaunch type:
> CastMap<dynamic, dynamic, String, dynamic> 01-25 21:17:11.568  3789
> 3838 I flutter : onLaunch 01-25 21:17:11.571  3789  3838 I flutter :
> --->>>> onLaunch {collapse_key: com.example.flutterapptestfcmmessaging, google.original_priority:
> high, google.sent_time: 1548447425689, google.delivered_priority:
> high, foo: bar, google.ttl: 2419200, from: 945032663190, id: 1,
> click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, google.message_id:
> 0:15484474256938..., status: done} 01-25 21:17:11.573
> 3789  3838 I flutter : onLaunch type: CastMap<dynamic, dynamic,
> String, dynamic> 01-25 21:17:11.574  3789  3838 I flutter : onLaunch
> foo: bar

I get my `printDebug` function with `adb`:

```
$ logcat -e "onLaunch" -v color
```

So in `onMessage` you can get the foo field like that

```
print("onMessage foo: ${message['data']['foo']}");
```

and in `onLaunch` you can get it like that:

```
debugPrint("onLaunch foo: " + message['foo']);
```

**UDATE:** iOS device

The above debugging session is for an Android device.

On a iOS device in order to get the console output of the device you could use [Apple App Configurator 2](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344) or the **`Console` application** (from `Utilities` folder inside your `Applications` folder):

on `onMessage` you will receive:

```
{status: done, google.c.a.e: 1, id: 1, aps: {alert: {title: Test Notification, body: Test Notification at 26/01/2019}}, gcm.message_id: 0:15485106,,,, foo: bar, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK}
```

and on `onResume` and `onLaunch`:

```
{status: done, google.c.a.e: 1, id: 1, aps: {alert: {title: Test Notification, body: Test Notification at 26/01/2019}}, gcm.message_id: 0:15485109..., foo: bar, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK}
```

They are the same, so I suggest to check the platform before getting your custom data in `onMessage`.

For that you could use [`dart.io` library `Platform`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/Platform-class.html) class:

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  print("onMessage Android foo: ${message['data']['foo']}");
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  debugPrint("onMessage iOS foo: " + message['foo']);
}
```